# Como puedo agregar un parámetro en todas las funciones de una clase

Tags: python, class, python-requests, diseño-de-clases, django-class-based-views

si tengo una clase:

```
class MyClass:
    def my_func1(self, my_parameter):
        pass

    def my_func2(self, my_parameter):
        pass

    def my_func3(self, my_parameter):
        pass
```

¿existe una forma de agregar my_parameter en todas las funciones sin necesidad de agregarlo manualmente en cada función?.

Comment: El código de la pregunta tiene errores de sintaxis y faltan cosas.

Comment: Aparte de que tu código tenga errores, como te dice @CandidMoe, sería conveniente que aclararas qué es lo que esperas conseguir con algún ejemplo. Si hay algún parámetro compartido por todos los métodos que no quieras añadir siempre, es que igual necesitas tenerlo definido como variable de instancia, inicializada en el método `__init__()`, y que sea común al resto de métodos.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tendría? Aún si hubiera una forma de añadir ese parámetro "automágicamente" usando código (sería quizás posible usand metaclases), de todas formas si los métodos ya están implementados y no usan ese parámetro ¿para qué pasárselo?

Comment: gracias por responder ya lo corregi. Sucede que ya tengo una clase con sus funciones definidas y tengo un cambio en la que todos reciben un parámetro de entrada. No lo puedo colocar en el ```__init__```, porque este parámetro no se crea al momento de instanciar la clase si no se recibe al llamar cada función y aunque se llama igual en cada función su valor es diferente.